# No tests were found when running Archunit tests using JUnit5

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, java-8, junit5, archunit

I've a very simple Archunit test case running in IntelliJ IDE with Java 17 and JUnit 5. I've added the following dependency in `pom.xml`:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>archunit-junit5-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Below is my test class:

```
    import com.tngtech.archunit.junit.*;
    import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ArchRule;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    
    import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.*;
    import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ImportOption.*;

        @AnalyzeClasses(
            packages = "com.my.package.name",
            importOptions = {DoNotIncludeTests.class})
        public class ArchitectureTests {
        
          @ArchTest
          public static final ArchRule testControllerNaming =
              classes()
                  .that()
                  .areAnnotatedWith(Controller.class)
                  .should()
                  .haveSimpleNameEndingWith("Controller");
        }
```

When I run the test case, I keep getting "No tests were found". What am I missing?

EDIT 1: I got a part of it working using JUnit annotations. The code below works:

```
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClasses;
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ClassFileImporter;
import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ArchRule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.*;

public class ArchitectureTests {
  JavaClasses jc = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("com.my.package.name");

  public static final ArchRule testControllerNaming =
      classes()
          .that()
          .areAnnotatedWith(Controller.class)
          .should()
          .haveSimpleNameEndingWith("Controller")
          .allowEmptyShould(true);

  @Test
  public void testControllerName() {
    testControllerNaming.check(jc);
  }
}
```

However, this only works when run directly from the IDE. Maven doesn't seem to find these tests.
Furthermore, the `@ArchTest` annotation doesn't seem to work. I can only run the method-based tests annotated with `@Test`. I can't run any field-based test directly annotated with `@ArchTest`.
I compared my code to the examples listed in the official Github repo of ArchUnit and I can't seem to find any difference that may lead me to find any reason for my code not working. I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/1157#issuecomment-1693870939)'s an example of a Maven project with lots of ArchUnit tests. Does that one work for you? Maybe you can work out the differences to your case starting from there.

Comment: @Manfred I went through them but honestly, I can't seem to find a difference. I did find a work-around (added a snippet of the code above) but it's rather crude compared to the proposed working solution provided by ArchUnit.

Comment: ArchUnit's JUnit support will definitely help you to avoid that boilerplate code (and performance problems if you import your classes manually for every test). But you must also agree that we need your `pom.xml` to help you debug a problem that only shows up in the Maven build... ;)

Answer (score 0):

As @Manfred hinted, the problem was with my `pom.xml`. When I didn't get the expected results at the first go, I started adding a bunch of dependencies that were probably not needed and maybe they were conflicting with each other. I had the following dependencies added:

1. archunit
2. archunit-junit5
3. archunit-junit5-api
4. archunit-junit5-engine
5. junit-platform-engine (explicitly added when the test cases were not being identified by maven)

I removed everything and just kept `archunit-junit5=1.1.0`. It just worked out. Below is the working test case that works both when run directly from the IDE or maven - as expected.

```
import com.tngtech.archunit.junit.AnalyzeClasses;
import com.tngtech.archunit.junit.ArchTest;
import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ArchRule;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.*;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ImportOption.*;

@AnalyzeClasses(
    packages = "com.my.package.name",
    importOptions = {DoNotIncludeTests.class})
public class ArchitectureTests {
  @ArchTest
  public static final ArchRule testControllerNaming =
      classes()
          .that()
          .areAnnotatedWith(Controller.class)
          .should()
          .haveSimpleNameEndingWith("Controller");
}
```

Comment: I'm glad that you could solve your problem. For the next time, it would be nice to post the `pom.xml` (if that's the root cause) of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) already in your issue  to give everybody the chance to post an answer.